# VS Code Weird Highlight in Terminal

Tags: bash, terminal, windows-subsystem-for-linux, visual-studio-code

[This screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIUbE.png) shows a weird highlighting in the VS Code terminal running a Bash on Ubuntu on Windows session. It starts part way through the output of the first PS1 prompt and continues on. It stays like this throughout the rest of the session - even if I go into programs like `vim`.

The `.bashrc` is stock with a few changes to the `PATH` and an added environment variable - I imagine these would not create such a problem. Does anyone know how to get rid of the highlighting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WSL updated, and now the Bash on Ubuntu on Windows shell works just fine - no weird highlighting. I still do not know why it was an issue to begin with, though. If anyone else hits this issue, I guess stick it out until an update.